# DropDownList inside TELERIX AJAX bound grid doesn't work (all EditorTemplates) ASP.NET MVC2 extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik Grid, AJAX binded.

I've added an EditorTemplate to create a DropDownList.

When I push edit / insert in the grid - I can see the DropDownList, but when I try to use it - it doesn't work.

so I've added an int test to the viewmodel, decorated it with the same UIHINT, 
and added it to the view.

The DropDownList works great.

What can cause Telerik's grid to disable that activity ?
I've the same problem with the DateTime component, I get the "button" to show the component, but pressing it yields nothing.

UPDATE: changing the DropDownList from :

```
Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
        .Name("ActivityID")
                .BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["DropActivities"], "Id", "Name"))
```

to:

```
Html.DropDownList(null /* the "name" should be null - proper "name"" attribute will be set by the runtime */,
           new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["DropActivities"] /*a list of all employee names */, 
       "Id", "Name"))
```

Made it work inside the grid, but... when I try to update, I Get 500 server error.. it looks like the selection doesn't pass well back to the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like a confirmed bug with telerik.

Here is the post from their forum: [Script Registrar Not Loading Scripts for Controls used in Client Templates](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/script-registrar-not-loading-scripts-for-controls-used-in-client-templates.aspx)

I did applied the patch and it didn't solved the problem waiting for the next version.

EDIT: make sure the bound variable apears only once - that might cause the "lockdown".